# Start new line without breaking current one (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

In intelliJ Idea, you can start a new line via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
Is there a shortcut or extension that can add this functionality?

Comment: `Ctrl+Enter` and ``Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Comment: neither Ctrl Enter or Ctrl Shift Enter work (though that may be because I'm on a laptop)

Comment: which key is bound to `Insert Line Above` and `Insert Line Below`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an extension that ports IntelliJ's shortcuts into VSC
[IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings)

Answer (score 3):

Starting a new line without breaking current in Visual Studio Code(without Github Copilot).

For Mac: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>

For Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: The `Ctrl + Enter` is getting replaced to enter Git Copilot Completions Panel.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone with their `ctrl+enter` just got replaced by Git Copilot Completions Panel, you can just open `Keyboard Shortcut` menu with `Ctrl+K`
`Ctrl+S`, search for `Git Copilot Completions Panel`, right click then delete keybinding.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to enable wordwrapping within the vscode preferences to get your desired effect