# How can I jump past suggested line ending characters in VS Code to enter a new line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I code in CSS I get suggestion which ends with semicolon but then I have to click on the right arrow then enter to jump to the next line. I want to be able to only click on enter 2 times and jump to the next line without dragging semicolon with me ex: `text-align: center`. Here when I click enter I drag semicolon to the next line which means I have to use the right arrow and it's annoying  when  coding a lot of line in CSS.

Thank you.

Comment: thanks but there no extension i guess to only use the key word "enter" before semicolon ?

Comment: what happens if you press `Ctrl+Enter` when the cursor is anywhere on a line?

Comment: it work perfectly and its open a up line and alt + enter it open a down line ./

Comment: also try `Shift+Ctrl+Enter`, most likely you do not use Windows because `Alt+Enter` does nothing on my computer for the editor window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start new line without breaking current one (Visual Studio Code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73355882/start-new-line-without-breaking-current-one-visual-studio-code)

Comment: thanks guys alt + enter has solved my issue thank you againe